# Python mmap.mmap() to bytes-like object?

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator, mmap

The documentation for [`mmap`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/mmap.html) says that "Memory-mapped file objects behave like both [`bytearray`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytearray) and like [file objects](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-file-object)."

However, that doesn't seem to extend to a standard `for` loop: At least for Python 3.8.5 on Linux which I'm currently using, each `mmap.mmap()` iterator element is a single-byte `bytes`, while for both a `bytearray` and for normal file access each element is an `int` instead.  **Update.** Correction: For normal file access it is a variable-sized `bytes`; see below.

Why is that?  And more importantly, how can I efficiently get a bytes-like object from an `mmap`, so one where not only indexing but also `for` gives me an `int`?  (By efficiently, I mean that I'd like to avoid additional copying, casting, etc.)

---

Here is code to demonstrate the behavior:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3.8

def print_types(desc, x):
    for el in setmm: break   ### UPDATE: bug here, `setmm` should be `x`, see comments
    # `el` is now the first element of `x`
    print('%-30s: type is %-30s, first element is %s' % (desc,type(x),type(el)))
    try: print('%72s(first element size is %d)' % (' ', len(el)))
    except: pass # ignore failure if `el` doesn't support `len()`

setmm = bytearray(b'hoi!')
print_types('bytearray', setmm)

with open('set.mm', 'rb') as f:
    print_types('file object', f)

with open('set.mm', 'rb') as f:
    setmm = f.read()
    print_types('file open().read() result', setmm)

import mmap
with open('set.mm', 'rb') as f:
    setmm = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0, prot=mmap.PROT_READ)
    print_types('file mmap.mmap() result', setmm)
```

which results in

```
bytearray                     : type is <class 'bytearray'>           , first element type is <class 'int'>
file object                   : type is <class '_io.BufferedReader'>  , first element type is <class 'int'>
file open().read() result     : type is <class 'bytes'>               , first element type is <class 'int'>
file mmap.mmap() result       : type is <class 'mmap.mmap'>           , first element type is <class 'bytes'>
                                                                        (first element size is 1)
```

---

**Update.** With the bug fixed that [furas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1832058/furas) kindly pointed out in the comments, the result becomes

```
bytearray                     : type is <class 'bytearray'>           , first element is <class 'int'>
file object                   : type is <class '_io.BufferedReader'>  , first element is <class 'bytes'>
                                                                        (first element size is 38)
file open().read() result     : type is <class 'bytes'>               , first element is <class 'int'>
file mmap.mmap() result       : type is <class 'mmap.mmap'>           , first element is <class 'bytes'>
                                                                        (first element size is 1)
```

Which answers what happens: For some reason iterating over an `mmap` is like iterating over a file, returning a `bytes` every time, but not with full lines like for a file, but single-byte chunks.

Still my main question is unchanged: How can I efficiently have an `mmap` behave like a bytes-like object (i.e., both indexing and `for` give `int`)?

Comment: you have mistake in `print_types` - it has to be `for el in x` instead of `for el in setmm` - and this gives different results. For `file object` it gives `bytes` instead of `int`

Comment: if you use `for`- loop directly on `file object` and `mmap` then you get `bytes` but if you use `f.read()` and `mmap.read()` then you get `int`. You get `int` also if you use index - ie. `mmap[0]`

Comment: @furas Thanks for pointing that out!  Updated the question w.r.t. the bug in my code.

Comment: @furas I have a library that works on a bytes-like object, and `mmap.read()` gives me such an object, however that requires copying that huge file, which is exactly what I don't want to do for efficiency.

Comment: can't you use `mmap.read(number)` to get only part of file ?

Comment: @furas No, I need to tokenize a huge file in its entirety, and I'd like to use a library that uniformly can use any bytes-like object (including `bytes` and `bytearray`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I efficiently have an mmap behave like a bytes-like object (i.e., both indexing and for give int)?

`bytes` is an object which contains data in memory.  But the whole point of `mmap` is to not load all the data into memory.

If you want to get a `bytes` object containing the entire content of a file, `open()` the file as normal and `read()` the entire content.  Using `mmap()` for this is working against yourself.

Perhaps you want to use `memoryview`, which can be constructed from `bytes` or `mmap()` and will give you a uniform API.

Comment: That's is, thanks! `memoryview(mmap.mmap(...))` works fine.  (Its performance still is slightly worse than a plain `open()` + `read()`, which feels a bit strange to me.  Perhaps that is because `read()` reads everything into memory at once, and iterating over the mmap probably reads the file in chunks...  Whatever, this exactly answers the question.)